# Laravel Query Exception on aggregate table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to move a Laravel 5.8 application to Azure, but when I run the application I've getting the following error;

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = email@email.com and `suspended_at` is not null and `users`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

Straight away I can see that the email address in the query isn't wrapped in quotes and wondered if this could be the problem, but at the same time I've copied this application directly from another Linux server where it worked perfectly.

The Azure web service is setup to run PHP 7.3.

Has anyone experienced this error before?

UPDATE:

Here's a snippet from the applications `database.php` file, which shows that it's configured to use SSL (SQL Database is on Azure).

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'sslmode' => env('DB_SSLMODE', 'prefer'),
            'options' => [
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY    => base_path('ssl/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem'),
            ]
        ]
```

I've double checked the database credentials in the applications `.env` file are correct. I'm using these same credentials to connect to the database using MySQL Workbench, I know they work.

If there is a problem connecting to the server, Laravel's logging isn't giving me any indication what the problem may be, is it a problem connecting to the host, are the credentials incorrect? Is it something else?

Comment: There is no such user in the database or there may be a database connection error.

Comment: The user exists in the database. There could be a connection error, but the error doesn't tell me that or indicate what the connection issue could be.

Comment: Set the storage folder folder permissions to 777

Comment: The storage folder already has permissions of 777

Comment: Open terminal go to  project folder run "composer update"

Comment: Dependancies are already up to date. You're just suggesting I try random things.

Comment: I wish I could connect you with AnyDesk.

Comment: did you try to connect to Azure directly from ur server using cert?

Comment: `'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),` - don't think it's necessary, you have to put url to host

Comment: I have removed the 'url' property but it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: try to connect from console to Azure - `mysql -h url --ssl-ca=path-to-pem.pem -P 3306 -u userName -p` and check if pem file is good

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed by using the direct hostname to the database server rather than relying on the Traffic Manager URL provided in Azure.